# remove any lines which level <30

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a request please, I am usng regular expression on notepad++ and i have my database and it contains lines like

```
test1 - Level : 12 - Role : Healer
test2 - Level : 30 - Role : Healer
test3 - Level : 35 - Role : Healer
test3 - Level : 162 - Role : Healer
```

I want it to remove any lines whose level <30 so the output should be

```
test2 - Level : 30 - Role : Healer
test3 - Level : 35 - Role : Healer
test3 - Level : 162 - Role : Healer
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    ^.*Level : [12]?[0-9]\b.*\R?
Replace: (empty)
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lXIjKv/1) showing that the logic is working.

Comment: Brilliant idea.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you please tell me the code if i want it to remove any levels less than 400? Also if possible please a description for the code!

Comment: @GlalAli Use the pattern `^.*Level : (?:[0-9]|[1-3]?[1-9][0-9])\b.*\R?`, and [see the regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/NPCjV5/1).

Comment: @tim ★★★★★   but what if I wanted it including 30,  means upto 31,  then what changes are necessary?